# Divergence theorem and a hemisphere

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm confused about applying the Divergence theorem to hemispheres.

Here is the statement:

[image]

As far as I understand, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880999/how-to-compute-int-h-f-cdot-nds-efficiently) question asks to compute  $\int\int_{S_1}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S$ over $$S_1=\{(x,y,z):z>0, x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2\}.$$ Here $E=\{(x,y,z): z>0,\ x^2+y^2+z^2\le R^2\}$. The boundary of $E$ is $S_1\cup S_2$, where $$S_2=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2=R^2\}.$$ So the divergence theorem reads $$\int\int_{S_1}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S+\int\int_{S_2}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S=\int\int\int_E\operatorname{div}\mathbf F\ dV.$$It is shown that for $\mathbf F$ in the cited question, $\operatorname {div}\mathbf F=1$ so $$\int\int\int_E \operatorname {div}\mathbf F\ dV=\text{volume of the hemisphere $E$}$$ and 
$$\int\int_{S_2}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S=\int\int_{S_2}\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\ d\ S=\\ \int\int_{S_2} \mathbf F(x,y,0)\cdot (0,0,-1)\ dS=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R-e^{-r^2}rdrd\phi=\pi (e^{-R^2}-1),$$ $\mathbf n$ being the outward unit normal.

And thus the integral we need equals $$\int\int_{S_1}=-\int\int_{S_2}+\int\int\int_V=\pi(1-e^{-R^2})+\frac{2}{3}\pi R^3.$$

My questions are:

- Is my interpretation correct?
- Did I use somehow that $z>0$ (as opposed to $z\ge 0$) in the definition of $S_1$? What if I had $z\ge 0$? Would the integral be the same?
- In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831981/calculating-a-flux-integral/2831992#2831992) question, should I also subtract the integral over the circle in the $xy$-plane from the divergence integral to obtain the final answer?

Comment: Tip: multiple integral symbols are available as \int, \iint, \iiint. Like $$\int, \iint, \iiint. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_1$ really should be the *closed* hemisphere (i.e., $z\ge 0$). (And $E$ should likewise include $z=0$.) However, $S_2$ also needs to be a surface, not a curve. You did the computation for the disk $x^2+y^2\le R^2$, $z=0$, so your computation seems to be in the right direction. Since you didn't include $\mathbf F$ in your post (I can't chase it down while I'm typing an answer), I won't check the details.
One way to think about this physically/intuitively, is that whatever material flows across the bottom disk *plus* all the interior sources will tell you what flows out across the top hemisphere.

Comment: The original problem (with the definition of $\mathbf F$) is given in the first quoted link (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880999/how-to-compute-int-h-f-cdot-n-ds-efficiently); there $S_1$ is defined with $z > 0$. Do you mean there is a mistake in the original question? The present question is motivated by the answer given in the mentioned link.

Comment: In this question, $S_1$ also includes $z>0$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832074/a-flux-integral-evaluates-to-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, I'm saying the question is sloppily written, but that happens with calculus texts. Ordinarily, in a calculus course, we define integrals over closed regions, not open ones.

Comment: So apart from the fact that $S_2$ should be defined as a disk and the inequalities should be $\le $ everywhere instead of $<$, everything is fine ideologically? And for the future, if I encounter an integral over the open hemisphere, I can suppose that the authors meant the closed one, since the integrals along the open hemisphere isn't defined?

Comment: Yes. And it's good that you've mastered the idea of closing up a surface (like a hemisphere) by putting the "bottom" on so that you can apply the Divergence Theorem. That's an important thing.